# Why does sending files from GridFS via MVC4 take so much time?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4, mongodb-.net-driver, iis-8, gridfs

I want to send images stored in MongoDB using GridFS via a MVC4 Web app to the browser via my LAN environment, but it take ~500ms until the image is sent to the browser.

Google Chrome network inspector says most of the time is spent during "Waiting" while the actual "Receiving" takes ~1ms.

The MongoDB server is in the local network, so what can take so long to send an 10kb image?  I use Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2012 and the official mongo-csharp-driver via NuGet.

Here is my code of my "Files" controller which takes an object id and sends the data for this id:

```
public FileContentResult Files(string id)
{
    var database = new MongoClient(MyConnection).GetServer().GetDatabase("MyDB");
    var gridFs = new MongoGridFS(database);
    var bsonId = new BsonObjectId(id);
    var gridInfo = gridFs.FindOneById(bsonId);
    var bytes = GridInfoToArray(gridInfo);
    return new FileContentResult(bytes, "image/jpeg") { FileDownloadName = gridInfo.Name };
}

private byte[] GridInfoToArray(MongoGridFSFileInfo file)
{
    using (var stream = file.OpenRead())
    {
        var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Code to display the image in a View:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Files", new { id = objectIdOfMyImage) })"/>
```

Comment: How many records are in your collection? Also, have you tried running an `explain` on the from the shell? Maybe you're missing an index or something.

Comment: Currently there are only ~10 records for testing

Comment: What about running an `explain` on your query? Or checking the latency between your web server and your mongodb server?

Comment: Here is the output when calling `Explain()` on the `gridFs.Find(Query.EQ("_id", bsonId))` result: http://pastebin.com/bXeMX3hv

Answer (score 0):

How different are the results if you cache your Database and MongoGridFS instances?

```
// create static fields for _database & _gridFs
var database = _database ?? 
    (_database = new MongoClient(MyConnection).GetServer().GetDatabase("MyDB"));
var gridFs = _gridFs ?? 
    (_gridFs = new MongoGridFS(database));
```

I'm not sure how much overhead it incurs when you instantiate these, but it wouldn't hurt to move it outside of the method you're trying to optimize.